# Is there another way to pass values through a URL with PHP?

Tags: php, url

I am developing a site with user accounts. The URL for each is along the lines of:

```
www.site.com/profile.php?user=ChanceM
```

But, **I was wondering if there was another way to send values through the URL and grab them with PHP** with a URL more like this:

```
www.site.com/ChanceM
```

Or:

```
www.site.com/profile.php/ChanceM
```

I was just wondering if this were possible, because remembering the first URL isn't very user friendly. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you must of seen it done in lots of places.

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "URL rewriting".

Comment: Go search how web servers work.

Comment: Thanks Oli Charlesworth, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Apache yes - You need to look through the manual pages for [rewrite](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) rules. The link will tell you how to do this. Also look through the Apache documentation.

As for other servers I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly ways to do this but maybe not built right into php like the $_GET array is.  One thing you can do is in the apache configuration, replace the 404 page with a php script which gets url aimed at and redirects to a version like www.site.com/profile.php?user=ChanceM (and I think in mod_rewrite you can do this too).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it any of the ways you illustrated.

In the case of the first example, you have to use something like [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) which can transparently rewrite the friendly URL (site.com/Username) to the PHP script (site.com/profile.php?user=Username)

Using the second method, you have to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to access the data from the URL, and manually parse it into usable variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send "cleaner URL's" (Without doing some type of URL rewrite) you can use things like implode and parse url:

```
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
```

These methods allow you to pull various parts of the URL and use them

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `mod_rewite` in Apache.

Here's an example of a rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1`

You can test it here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/